# Is Indonesian Muslim being Lied to by Al Maidah 51?

Tags: khilafah, surat-al-maidah, government

Some politicians in Indonesia tell muslims that Al Maidah 51 tell them to only vote for muslim governors.

Are those politicians lying?

This is probably a bit of semantic.

What about if the muslim governor that the politicians favor is corrupt and plan to steal people money, and the politicians know it, and they tell the people to pick that muslim governor anyway by using Al Maidah 51.

> ۞ يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا لَا تَتَّخِذُوا الْيَهُودَ
>   وَالنَّصَارَىٰ أَوْلِيَاءَ ۘ بَعْضُهُمْ أَوْلِيَاءُ بَعْضٍ ۚ وَمَنْ
>   يَتَوَلَّهُمْ مِنْكُمْ فَإِنَّهُ مِنْهُمْ ۗ إِنَّ اللَّهَ لَا يَهْدِي
>   الْقَوْمَ الظَّالِمِينَ
>
> O you who have believed, do not take the Jews and the Christians as
>   allies. They are [in fact] allies of one another. And whoever is an
>   ally to them among you - then indeed, he is [one] of them. Indeed,
>   Allah guides not the wrongdoing people.
>
> ([Quran 5:51](https://quran.com/5/51))

Would it be correct to say that some people have been lied to by using Al Maidah 51?

Comment: So far, no answers explicitly say yes or no.

Comment: What I see is more of people should prefer muslim candidates, which is a very moderate position. No body says, no it's not a lie. A muslim must vote for muslim candidate no matter what. Nor do I hear anyone saying, it's a lie. A muslim can vote for anyone.

Comment: It is not the case. My [answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/48041) is a clear no, there should be no non-Muslim ruler in a Muslim country, and it is not my opinion; it is the Islamic stance.

Comment: Good. Can you please make that more clearly. There should be no non muslim ruler in a country where majority of the population is muslim.

Comment: This might be relevant [Can a Muslim vote for non-Muslim governors or presidents?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36294/can-a-muslim-vote-for-non-muslim-governors-or-presidents)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better ayah to use is probably this:

> The believers should not take the disbelievers as allies instead of the believers, and whoever does that Allah will have nothing to do with him, except when you are wary of them out of caution. Allah warns you to beware of [disobeying] Him, and toward Allah is the return. (3:28)

In the case of two equal or semi-equal candidates, according to this ayah Muslims should always prefer and vote for the Muslim candidate.

So, the message that they are saying is correct. Muslims should prefer Muslim candidate. In the case of corruption, the decision is harder but there should always be a bit of a bias for Muslim candidates.

Also, if the other non-muslim candidates are trying to secularize the country and remove Quranic Laws then voting for them is definitely not good regardless of their honesty. An honest evil is still evil.

Comment: So muslims should avoid secularization? You don't answer yes or no to the question

Comment: A bit of bias. How much? We didn't have quranic laws in Jakarta actually. Not in the first place. There are some laws like anti prostitution laws that causes much corruption. So, some politicians want to remove that

Comment: @Sharen . Yes, muslims should avoid secularization. Why would anti-prostitution laws cause corruption? This is the kind of things I am talking about. Removing anti-prostitution laws is definitely a bad thing and no one can as a muslim vote for a candidate that wants to do that.

Comment: Because prostitution is around anyway except that the guy doing it pays cops. What countries are you in? And what's wrong with secularization? It keeps Europe out of civil war for the last 50 years

Comment: In Indonesia, most laws are not enforced. It's just "there" to be "used" occasionally.

Comment: @SharenEayrs . ""And what's wrong with secularization?" To muslims secularization is taking the rights of Allah (the right to make laws) and giving it to people. "It's just "there" to be "used" occasionally." Being enforced occasionally is better than never being enforced. Islamically prostitution is not legal. Allowing it (or supporting a candidate who allows it over one who doesn't) isgoing against the Laws of Allah.

Comment: @SharenEayrs . "except that the guy doing it pays cops." If there is a problem of enforcement in your country, then you should be working to fix that. Not making bad things (like prostitution) legal just because you don't want to do the work to enforce it. So, support a candidate that wants to make the police less corrupted, not one who wants to make the illegal thing legal.

Comment: Well, I thought we got legislative branch to make laws? What countries you're from again?

Comment: @SharenEayrs "I thought we got legislative branch to make laws" Not in sharia.

Comment: @SharenEayrs . In Islam, laws come from Allah.

Comment: @TheZ as well as in all other religions. You don't explicitly say yes or no. You said muslims should prefer islamic candidate. Again, that is normal. Do muslims have obligation to vote for a muslim candidate no matter what?

Comment: In other word, does islam requires something stronger that no other religions demand, namely, voting for a muslim governor, instead of mere preferring

Answer (score 3):

Indonesia is a Muslim-majority country. There should be no non-Muslims running for a governor position in the first place. [Imam An-Nawawi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Nawawi) in his *Sharh* said:

> قال القاضي عياض أجمع العلماء على أن الإمامة لا تنعقد لكافر وعلى أنه لو طرأ عليه الكفر انعزل قال وكذا لو ترك إقامة الصلوات والدعاء إليها قال وكذلك عند جمهورهم البدعة
>
> <sub>**NOTE.** My own translation, so treat with care.</sub>
>
> [Qadi 'Ayyād](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qadi_Ayyad) said that there is an agreement among scholars that leadership is not to be given to a disbeliever, and [if given to a Muslim] if he shows signs of disbelief, he gets removed [from leadership]. He said that it is the same if he abandons prayers and calling for prayers, and for the majority of scholars this includes innovators [in religion].
>
> <sub>— [Sahih Muslim bi sharh al-Nawawi, Vol. 12, pp. 229](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1711/2796) (Arabic only)</sub>

[Ibn al-Mundhir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_al-Mundhir) was quoted saying the same ruling exactly in [*Ahkām Ahl al-Dhimma* 2/787](https://al-maktaba.org/book/21747/672#p3) (Arabic only) by [Ibn Qayyim al-Jawziyya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Qayyim*al-Jawziyya).

Those who are voting need to observe the criteria required in a leader in the Muslim world, and the first criterion is Islam. The majority of the scholars agree that this is based on:

> وَلَن يَجْعَلَ اللَّهُ لِلْكَافِرِينَ عَلَى الْمُؤْمِنِينَ سَبِيلًا
>
> and never will Allah give the disbelievers over the believers a way [to overcome them].
>
> <sub>— [Surat An-Nisa 4:141](https://quran.com/4/141)</sub>

I am not sure how you came to know that the Muslim governor is "planning to steal people's money." This is speculation that we are commanded not to do:

> يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا اجْتَنِبُوا كَثِيرًا مِّنَ الظَّنِّ إِنَّ بَعْضَ الظَّنِّ إِثْمٌ ۖ وَلَا تَجَسَّسُوا وَلَا يَغْتَب بَّعْضُكُم بَعْضًا ۚ أَيُحِبُّ أَحَدُكُمْ أَن يَأْكُلَ لَحْمَ أَخِيهِ مَيْتًا فَكَرِهْتُمُوهُ ۚ وَاتَّقُوا اللَّهَ ۚ إِنَّ اللَّهَ تَوَّابٌ رَّحِيمٌ
>
> O you who have believed, avoid much [negative] assumption. Indeed, some assumption is sin. And do not spy or backbite each other. Would one of you like to eat the flesh of his brother when dead? You would detest it. And fear Allah ; indeed, Allah is Accepting of repentance and Merciful.
>
> <sub>— [Surat Al-Hujurat 49:12](https://quran.com/49/12)</sub>

Assuming that the statement you made is accurate, and that the Muslim running for governor is planning to steal people's money, then look for another Muslim leader who does not plan on stealing people's money. This should not be a difficult task considering that premonition is obviously used in deciding whom to vote for.

You may refer to Islam Q&A's article ["Is it permissible to swear allegiance to a kaafir ruler?"](https://islamqa.info/en/82681) for more information.

Comment: What countries are you? Islam is majority on most western province. The eastern ones have different religions. Ahok got 44% of vote anyway with 30% of muslims picking him

Comment: @SharenEayrs, Islam SE is neither a site for debates nor for politics. You did not mention any specific regions within Indonesia itself so that *tarjīh* can be taken into consideration when responding. The answer is the Islamic view based on the majority of Indonesian population, not a political one.

Comment: It's okay. Good enough. So can you make this more firm. Yes muslim must vote for muslim governors that sort of thing? A mere preferring a muslim governor is a bit out of the scope of the question. Of course, people prefer those similar to them. The question ask if islam demands something much stronger.

Comment: Tarjih means fatwa, which means opinions. And yet you said it's not your opinion but "islam"

Comment: @SharenEayrs, I said in my comment that no *tarjih* was done, so no *fatwa* and no personal opinions. I suggest that you re-read the answer and the comments. If you want to get into further discussions, you may use [chat].

Comment: It's okay. I misunderstood. Sorry. The reason I ask is you said tarjih can be taken into consideration. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I really don't know which answer I should choose. TheZ seems to use more relevant verse.

Comment: @SharenEayrs, no difference which answer you choose long as the information is passed.

Comment: Cool. I hope I don't make anyone get mad here.